# Unable to pass correct table row's data to next activity

Tags: android, dynamic, row, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I'm fairly new to Android programming and have completed my first app except for one issue on passing data from a table row that is selected (onClick).  I've researched out here and tried most of the recommendations but I'm obviously missing something critical.  I am a little confused on the getTag/Id and setTag/Id so maybe that's where I'm going wrong.

A little background, the table can have 1 to N number of rows populated dynamically from database, each row being clickable. Once a row is clicked, I need to pass the unique data of that row to the next activity (using Bundle for that which works fine).  What doesn't work is that no matter which row I click, I only get the last row's data passed to the next activity and not the data of the clicked row.

Here's some of my pertinent code for the data add to row/table and onclick... What am I doing wrong to only get the last row's data?  Really appreciate anyone's help in pointing me in the right direction.

```
    public void addData(ArrayList<Auctions> auctions) {

        prevCity = "";
        currCity = "";
        prevDate = "";
        currDate = "";
        prevTime = "";
        currTime = "";
        prevUnit = "";
        currUnit = "";

        for (Iterator i = auctions.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Auctions p = (Auctions) i.next();

            if (p.getCity().equals(prevCity) && p.getDate().equals(prevDate) && p.getTime().equals(prevTime) && p.getSunit().equals(prevUnit)) {
                //skip to next unique record
            } else {

                /** Create a City TableRow dynamically **/
                row2 = new TableRow(this);
                row2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
                tvcity = new TextView(this);
                currCity = p.getCity();
                if (currCity.toString().equals(prevCity)) {
                    tvcity.setText("");
                } else {
                    //create a blank row to separate from previous city entries
                    row1 = new TableRow(this);
                    row1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tvdummy = new TextView(this);
                    tvdummy.setText("");
                    tvdummy.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    row1.addView(tvdummy);
                    auctions_table.addView(row1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    // work on the new city data
                    tvcity.setText(p.getCity());
                }

                tvcity.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tvcity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

                //add TextView data to row
                row2.addView(tvcity);

                // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
                auctions_table.addView(row2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                // Create date, time, and unit name row dynamically
                row3 = new TableRow(this);
                row3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                // Create TextViews to add to the Row -- Date and Time
                tvdate = new TextView(this);
                tvtime = new TextView(this);
                tvsunit = new TextView(this);

                currDate = p.getDate();
                currTime = p.getTime();
                currUnit = p.getSunit();

                if ((currDate.toString().equals(prevDate)) && (currTime.toString().equals(prevTime))) {
                    tvdate.setText("");
                    tvtime.setText("");
                } else {
                    tvdate.setText(p.getDate());
                    tvtime.setText(p.getTime());
                }

                if (currUnit.toString().equals(prevUnit)) {
                    tvsunit.setText("");
                } else {
                    tvsunit.setText("Dynamic UNIT");
                    tvsunit.setText(p.getSunit());
                }

                tvdate.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tvdate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                tvtime.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tvtime.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                tvsunit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tvsunit.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));                

                //add TextView data to row
                row3.addView(tvdate);
                row3.addView(tvtime);
                row3.addView(tvsunit);

                row3.setId(t);
                row3.setFocusable(false);
                //row3.setClickable(true);
                row3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
                    //public OnClickListener tablerowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Get the selected row's data
                            //row3.getId();
                            Bundle basket2 = new Bundle();
                            basket2.putString("ustate", state.getText().toString());
                            basket2.putString("abbrev", abbrev);
                            basket2.putString("ucity", currCity);
                            basket2.putString("uname", currUnit);
                            basket2.putString("auctiondate", currDate);
                            basket2.putString("auctiontime", currTime);

                            Intent StAuctions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StorageAuctionDetails.class);
                            StAuctions.putExtras(basket2);
                            StAuctions.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(StAuctions);
                            // Closing screen
                            //finish();
                        }
                    });  
                row3.setBackgroundResource(drawable.list_selector_background);

                // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
                auctions_table.addView(row3, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                
            }

            prevCity = currCity;
            prevDate = currDate;
            prevTime = currTime;
            prevUnit = currUnit;
            t++;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to get these variables based on what they are when onClick is activated:

```
 basket2.putString("ustate", state.getText().toString());
                            basket2.putString("abbrev", abbrev);
                            basket2.putString("ucity", currCity);
                            basket2.putString("uname", currUnit);
                            basket2.putString("auctiondate", currDate);
                            basket2.putString("auctiontime", currTime);
```

Those valued will be for whatever the last time you ran through  your iteration.

You need to create a new "basket" for each row entry.  Not in the click listener, but in the iteration loop, and make that basket the tag for that row, with something like this:

```
row3.setTag(basket2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't decrypt your code sufficiently enough. But what I would suggest is that in your `onClick()`, put in `Log.v("Row id is: ", Integer.toString(v.getId()))` and see in LogCat if every time you click, it returns the same value.

Also, if I'm writing similar features, I might want to perform the extraction of row information in the `onClick()`, so information gets extracted from row and put into bundle on the fly, rather than passing the values into bundle during the iterator. Something like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String a;    //extras for bundle
    Bundle basket2 = new Bundle();
    //iterate row's children and assign values to string here
    for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildSize(); i++){
        TextView t = (TextView)v.getChildAt(i);
        //assignment
        basket2.putString("someKey", a);
    }
    //send your intent
}
```

Comment: I get row = 4 no matter which row I select, so yes, it returns same value

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your second comment.  How would I extract the row info in the onClick?  Previously, I had the onClick outside of the iterator and still got the same result.

Comment: @Sheila what exactly is `t` in `row3.setId(t);`? I can't find where you declare it.

Comment: Here's what I do prior to the code listed...  I passed data from a prior activity, queried database using that data, parsed the json and built array of data which is the input to this code.  Code is a bit "complicated" because I didn't do a distinct on my query so I bypass duplicate rows in the code.  Everything in app works except getting the right row set here to pass to next activity.

Comment: @Sheila should try `Integer.toString(v.getId())` instead of `row3.getId()`. That way it tests which view `View v` is in `onClick()`. That was my fault suggesting the wrong code, sorry.

Comment: Ok based on "Integer.toString(v.getId())", the id is definitely changing and accurate to the row being clicked on.  Now I just have to figure out how to use that to extract that row's data.  Really appreciate your guidance.  Was starting to pull my hair out ;)

Comment: @Sheila try `v.getChildSize()` and `v.getChildAt()` since you know what kinds of view the children of the row are. And for `TextView` you just need to `text.getText()`.

Comment: Would it work to loop through rows within the onClick until row3 id matches the v.getId() to get the data for that row?  Maybe using a second iterator??? Just seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @Sheila well, since you are getting the corresponding click, the `View v` in `onClick()`'s parameter will be the row clicked on. So you just need to use that. No need to match id. I've updated answer in second comment to show the concept. However using the `v` you only get stuff in that particular row which is clicked. But I think that's what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yes.  I missed your previous comment.  I've moved the basket build to each row outside the onClick. Let me see if I can get the onClick code right using the v.  Making a whole lot more sense now.  You're awesome!

Comment: This worked!!!  I do have a small bug within the code (one of the rows didn't return anything) but I can figure that out on my own.  Thank you! Thank you!